# Could resonance be used to break free an object covered in ice?

Tags: science-based, physics

This article references breaking ice through resonance, but is not specific enough for my case: [Resonance method of ice destruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_method_of_ice_destruction)

I have a situation where I would like a robot character to break free a mining drill that is completely encased in a block of ice. Could this character use resonance to break the ice? If possible, what would the character need to create this resonance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked article has to do with clearing ice from navigable waters, as far as I can tell.  It is pretty obtuse!  I am not sure how having something move across the ice produces resonance.

For an item covered with ice, you are probably thinking about something like a tone at the [resonant frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance) being used to break a wine glass.

> Like mechanical resonance, acoustic resonance can result in
>   catastrophic failure of the object at resonance. The classic example
>   of this is breaking a wine glass with sound at the precise resonant
>   frequency of the glass, although this is difficult in practice.

At the resonant frequency a solid object will vibrate a lot because the successive sound waves add energy - this is why the wine glass breaks.  In theory that might be possible with the ice but it could be possible with the drill or a very hard object like the drill bit.

You would need something to project sound (like an amplifier) and something to create sounds at various frequencies (dare I hope an electric guitar?) until you found the resonant frequency for the drill.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the clarification! Haha an electric guitar might just do it.